# Wall time profiling for multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, wall-time

I have two applications: one is multithreaded and one is completely sequential. Both applications perform the same task. I am trying to calculate the speedup of the multithreaded application. Somehow, I am getting more wall time for multithreaded code (`147.19 us`) as compared to sequential one (`41 us`). Is there any other way for wall time profiling?

```
#include "iostream"
#include "ctime"
#include "thread"
#include "chrono"
#include "iomanip"

#include <sys/time.h>

int deltaTime(struct timeval *tv1, struct timeval *tv2){
    return ((tv2->tv_sec - tv1->tv_sec)*1000000)+ tv2->tv_usec - tv1->tv_usec;
}

void execute_for_wallTime(int wall_time) 
{
    struct timeval  tvStart, tvNow;
    gettimeofday(&tvStart, NULL);

    for (int m = 0; wall_time; ++m){
      gettimeofday(&tvNow, NULL);
      if(deltaTime(&tvStart,&tvNow) >=wall_time) { 

        return;
      }
   } 
}

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();
   auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


   //multi-thread code 

   // std::thread t1(execute_for_wallTime, 10);
   // std::thread t2(execute_for_wallTime, 13);
   // std::thread t3(execute_for_wallTime, 16);
   // t1.join();
   // t2.join();
   // t3.join();

   //Sequential Code

   execute_for_wallTime(10);
   execute_for_wallTime(13);
   execute_for_wallTime(16);

   std::clock_t c_end = std::clock();
   auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "CPU time used: "
             << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms\n"
             << "Wall clock time passed: "
             << std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro>(t_end- 
                t_start).count()
             << " us\n";   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered that your multi threaded implementation maybe actually *is* slower than you single threaded one?

Comment: What optimization levels are you using, what compiler and what OS if any?

Comment: Since you don't show the actual "code to run" it's impossible for us to say. You have to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Kindly check now, It is a minimal complete example

Comment: @Ron OS: Linux, Compiler: GCC 6.4.0

Comment: @BaummitAugen This might be the case, But I am not sure how to check that. I tried to calculated the wall time in each separate thread but it gives completely different value each time I run the application. If you check the above code. you will see that it gives more time for sepuential than parallel code.

Comment: You're simply waiting to short time in your function. Try multiplying the time to wait by 1000 and you will see a difference in the other (and expected) direction. The extra time you have now for the threaded version is the time to set up, get running, and tear down the threads.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it makes sense now. Now, I can see some speedup. Thanks